# Why modifying gravity to a fixed distance cant solve dark matter?

Tags: dark-matter, modified-gravity, galaxy-rotation-curve

I quote Sabine Hossenfelder:

> "A modification becoming important at a fixed distance however could never explain the observed rotation velocities for spiral galaxies, whose constant asymptotic value depends on the luminosity of the galaxy, a relation which is known as the [Tully-Fisher relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tully%E2%80%93Fisher_relation)."

Why cant a theory of modified gravity be constructed based on distancce invariance instead of acceleration invariance (as MOND) to match the rotation curve dynamics of galaxies?

Comment: What do you mean by "cant [sic] solve dark matter"?

Comment: @hft Why a theory of modified gravity cant be constructed so that gravity changes at a particular distance instead of a particular acceleration to make the galaxy dynamics fit the observed velocities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Milgrom (MOND) showed, the v(r) data for spiral galaxies follows Newton until the radial acceleration
$$\frac{v^2}{r}=a(r)=\frac{GM}{r^2}=a_0$$
The data shows $a_0$ to be the same value for all spiral galaxies.  For a Newtonian acceleration much smaller than $a_0$, the acceleration is postulated to be equal the geometric mean of Newton and $a_0$.  That is
$$\frac{v^2}{r}=a(r)=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r^2}a_0}$$  Notice that the $r$ on both sides cancel out and the tangential velocity becomes constant $v=\sqrt{GMa_0}\quad$ as is actually observed.

Now $M\approx2L$ where the galaxy mass $M$ is in solar masses, and the galaxy luminosity $L$ is in solar luminosities. Then we get the Tully-Fisher relation mentioned by Sabine
$$ v^4\propto L $$

As to your original question, spiral galaxy's data agree with modifying Newton at less than a universal acceleration $a_0$ rather than at greater than a universal radius. Stated differently, $v(r)$ does not flatten at a universal r, but instead flattens when the Newtonian acceleration equals a universal $a_0$.